# execl()-ing in parent process: SIGCHLD caught by ps

Tags: linux, unix, exec, fork, sigchld

I'm doing an assignment on fork(),exec() and related UNIX calls where I need to show the zombie state of a (child) process. Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
pid = vfork();  //used vfork() for showing z state
if(pid>0)
  {
    (some sorting code)
    execl("/bin/ps","/bin/ps","a",(char*)0);             
  }
```

What I expect is:

```
(child's output)
(parent's output)
(Output of the ps command where I then would be able to show a 'defunct' entry)
```

What I get is:

```
(child's output)
(parent's output) 
No ps command output. Instead I get: Signal 17 (CHLD) caught by ps (procps version 3.2.8)
```

However, when `sleep(int time)` (some integer time in seconds) is inserted before the `execl` call, I get the desired output and no Signal errors are reported.

What's happening here? Does `ps` becomes the new parent of the (as yet-zombie) child?
And why does the `ps` command not execute? What does `sleep()` do that makes `ps` to execute as required?

I'm new to POSIX/Linux programing so any relevance of this `SIGCHLD` signal with respect to my particular situation would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is "(some sorting code)"?  If there is any chance that it might trigger a system call, it might be unsafe or at least undefined.  Usually you can only do *trivial* things (e.g. a bunch of calculations that don't allocate memory or call the OS) before calling some `execXX()` function in a child.

Comment: (some sorting code) is just code for selection sort of an array of integers. Haven't used any other system calls,no pointers,malloc() either.

Comment: @KevinGrant: With `vfork()`, true. With normal `fork()`, no.

Comment: It may depend on the UNIX variant but I've definitely seen versions of normal `fork()` with caveats on what children can do.

Comment: Note that in general, the only safe things to do in a `vfork()` child are calling `exec*()`, `_exit()`, and/or modifying a variable of type `pid_t` to store the result of `vfork()`. If you want to wait for the child, use `fork()` and one of the `wait*()` family of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I think what's happening is this:

- Your child starts and does the sorting code while the parent blocks.
- The child exits.
- The parent does it's half of the `if`, executing `ps`.
- After `ps` is started, `SIGCHLD` is sent to the parent process because of the termination of the child (signals can be slow and unpredictable)
- If you add the sleep, `SIGCHLD` is delivered to the parent, who ignores it, and then control passes to `ps`.

Comment: What does "child is still alive" mean? Isn't it a zombie already? I'm using `vfork()` which causes the parent to wait until the child's state has changed(we could, probably assume 'terminated' as a 'state change' here) So,at the time of execting `execl`, child process _has_ to have already terminated by way of completion.

Comment: @black_stallion: Hm. I just read up in the man page, and your right.

Comment: `system("ps")` would be a quick-fix, but I am hoping to understand why `execl` cannot, apparently, be used.

Comment: @black_stallion: What do you do in the child? What code is in the `else` branch of your `if`?

Comment: Two `printf` statements followed by a sort function call(again,no sys calls used in this function) and an `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` before the ending `}`

Comment: +1 (Can't upvote yet!)Yes, that's a plausible explanation. In that case,it seems that, `ps`, after receiving signals such as `SIGCHLD`, does not itself execute. Perhaps this is implementation-specific..?

Comment: @black_stallion: Probably it is implementation specific. And if the answer helped, you can always accept the answer by clicking the check mark bellow the vote count. I'd upvote the question again if I could, great question.

Comment: @black_stallion: Sure. Just keep asking and answering, and you can get very far very quick. Any user who puts this much into a first question is a great member of this community.

Comment: Yep;) `SO` is simply great! Just wanted my question to help and be helped!

Comment: @black_stallion: Great job with that. It's really nice to come across a well formatted, specific, answerable question. I'd give it 20 +1s if I could.

Comment: Hehe! A Problem Well-stated is Half-solved! Now, where did I get _that_?!

Comment: @black_stallion: Ooh! Shiny quote!

Answer (score -1):

**Title**

ps -ef fails with "Signal 17 (CHLD) caught by ps (procps version 3.2.8)"" on Redhat 6.6

**Description**

When running a ps -ef command on Redhat 6.6 it fails with the following error:
"Signal 17 (CHLD) caught by ps (procps version 3.2.8)"

**Cause**

This is a 3rd Party issue.
Redhat have created the following article to track the issue:

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1235753

**Resolution**

Please refer to the Redhat article for the latest workarounds.    https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1235753
These include the renaming of the libfreebl3.chk files as follows:

```
# mv /lib/libfreebl3.chk /lib/libfreebl3.chk-bz1153759
# mv /lib64/libfreebl3.chk /lib64/libfreebl3.chk-bz1153759
```

**Additional Information**

This appears to have been fixed by RedHat now. See RHBA-2014:1867